# angular firebase doesnt reflect changes on fullcalendar view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, firebase, fullcalendar

im using Firebase ( angularfire ) and fullcalendar plugin with my angular app, I can create new objects and see the results on firebase db but I don't see the the result in the view (I do see them only when I refresh the page).

for testing purpose I used the the `dayClick()` event of fullcalendar to trigger the `$add` function of firebase:

Controller:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("appCal");
    app.controller('meetingsCtrl', meetingsCtrl);

    function meetingsCtrl($scope, $http, $location, $log, $firebaseArray, $timeout) {

        var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

        $scope.fireEvents = $firebaseArray(ref);

        $scope.weekNumbers = true;
        $scope.aspectRatio = 3;
        $scope.editable = true;

        $scope.eventDrop = function (event, delta, revertFunc) {
            // todo event drop
        };

        $scope.dayClick = function (date, jsEvent, view) {
            $scope.fireEvents.$add({ title: 'new meeting...', start: date.format() });
        }
    }
})();
```

Directive:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("appCal");

    app.directive("sbCalendar", function () {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.fireEvents.$loaded(function () {
                    $(element).fullCalendar({

                        header: {
                            left: 'prev,next today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                        },
                        eventLimit: scope.weekNumbers,
                        aspectRatio: scope.aspectRatio,
                        events: scope.fireEvents,
                        editable: scope.editable,
                        eventDrop: scope.eventDrop,
                        dayClick: scope.dayClick

                    });
                });
            } 
        } 
    });
})();
```

Comment: Angular-UI ui-calendar implements a directive that uses full calendar. You might want to look at their source code to see how they do it. [Angular-UI UI calendar source code](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/blob/master/src/calendar.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out how it is done by the Angular UI team.

```
/*
*  AngularJs Fullcalendar Wrapper for the JQuery FullCalendar
*  API @ http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/
*
*  Angular Calendar Directive that takes in the [eventSources] nested array object as the ng-model and watches it deeply changes.
*       Can also take in multiple event urls as a source object(s) and feed the events per view.
*       The calendar will watch any eventSource array and update itself when a change is made.
*
*/
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/blob/master/src/calendar.js

Comment: thanks mate, I have tried this directive wrapper and indeed it does all the hard work for me :)